# What can I achieve with Azure Firewall networking rule that cannot be done by Azure Virtual Manager security admin rules

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

We can create [Security Admin Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network-manager/concept-security-admins) in Virtual Network Manager

> Security admin rules are global network security rules that enforce security policies defined in the rule collection on virtual networks. These rules can be used to Allow, Always Allow, or Deny traffic across virtual networks within your targeted network groups. These network groups can only consist of virtual networks within the scope of your virtual network manager instance. Security admin rules can't apply to virtual networks not managed by a virtual network manager.

[image]

Network rule collection in Azure Firewall

- is used to allow or block network traffic based on the source or destination IP address, port, and protocol.
- it operates at layer 4 (transport layer) of the OSI model and can be used to filter traffic based on IP address, port, and protocol.

For me this sounds like similar concepts. Of course Azure Firewall is more comprehensive as it offer DNAT, networking and application rules. But if we compare only Networking rules to Security admin rules they appears to be very similar.

What can be achieved by Azure Firewall networking rules that is not possible to achieve using Security admin rules?

Comment: Security admin rules are global network security rules that enforce security policies defined in the rule collection on virtual networks.

Comment: So, below would be the differences:
 
Azure Firewall provides application layer filtering capabilities, allowing you to create rules based on fully qualified domain names (FQDNs), URLs, and applications. NSGs, on the other hand, operate at the network layer and cannot filter traffic based on application-layer information.
Azure Firewall integrates with Azure Threat Intelligence, allowing you to create rules based on known malicious IP addresses and domains. This capability is not available with NSGs.

Comment: Azure Firewall supports network address translation (NAT), which allows outbound traffic from Azure resources to be translated to a public IP address. NSGs do not provide NAT functionality.

Comment: But comparing only aspects Networking rules from Azure Firewall, to Security Admin rules. I know that Azure Firewall does far more (like you mentioned NAT and application rules).

Answer (score 0):

As discussed over comments, comparing Azure Firewall's Networking Rules and Azure Virtual Manager security admin rules is like comparing oranges and apples.
If we only focus on the difference in terms of Network Rules of Firewall and Security admin rules:

- Security admin rules can explicitly support ESP and AH protocols while Firewall Rules don't
- You can have FQDN and IP Group as additional Destination type with Firewall Rules while security admin rules only support IP addresses and Service Tag.

Again, they serve different scenarios - for example,

- With Security admin rules, you have an option to terminate traffic evaluation without ever checking NSG
- But with Firewall network rules, the originating traffic first has to go through it's associated NSG (either NIC or subnet) before being processed by the Firewall's network Rules.

If you have a specific requirement/use case, please do let me know and I can probably suggest if Azure Firewall or Virtual Network Manager suits your requirement best.